# Karate - Matching 2 JSON objects for values but applying regex to one element of objects

Tags: karate

I have 2 json as follows:

a: [{"code":"00","name":"A","iconUrl":"https:env1.test.png"}, {"code":"01","name":"B"}]

b: [{"iconUrl":"https:env2.test.png", "code":"00","name":"A"}, {"code":"01","name":"B"}]

I want to compare the 2 json objects. I tried match contains only.

My test is failing due to mismatch of env1 and env2 in iconUrl. By any chance is there a way out to resolve it by applying regex for iconUrl and not affecting the validation for code and number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible ways, here is one:

```
* def first = [{"code":"00","name":"A","iconUrl":"https:env1.test.png"}, {"code":"01","name":"B"}]
* def second = [{"iconUrl":"https:env2.test.png", "code":"00","name":"A"}, {"code":"01","name":"B"}]
* second[0].iconUrl = '#string'
* match first == second
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Peter Thomas, but my json array has multiple elements. In few of the objects icon url is there and in others it is not. How to handle that?

i tried 
* second[*].iconUrl = '#string'
but this didnt work